# getenv Won't Display My Environment Variables in PHP

Tags: php, environment-variables

I have set up a .env file to hold my environmental variables.  If I **var_dump($_ENV)**, it shows all of my key pairs just as they are in my .env file so I know that PHP is seeing the environmental variables correctly.  But if I echo out a getenv of one of the environmental variables, I get an empty string.

```
$port = $_ENV["DATABASE_PORT"];
echo $port  // echos out 3306
```

This displays the correct port of 3306

```
$port = getenv("DATABASE_PORT");
echo $port  // echos out an empty string
```

This displays nothing, just an empty string

Any thoughts as to why the $_ENV is getting populated, but getenv won't pull a value?

Comment: How are you serving your file? There's a note in the document page [link](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getenv.php):
Beware that when using this function with PHP built-in server – i.e. php -S localhost:8000 – it will return boolean FALSE.

Comment: I am actually just using the PHP file as a cronjob to clean my database and delete files from Amazon S3.  I'm not serving it through Apache.